# Linking error LNK2001 when using Boost in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, boost, linker

I'm using Boost 1.54 and Qt 5.3.2 in Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to use the static libs of Boost Filesystem. However, whenever I try to build my application, I get the following linking errors:

```
libboost_filesystem-mt.lib(path.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>(unsigned int)" (__imp_??0?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@QAE@I@Z)
libboost_filesystem-mt.lib(path.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __thiscall std::locale::_Locimp::_Locimp(class std::locale::_Locimp const &)" (__imp_??0_Locimp@locale@std@@AAE@ABV012@@Z)
libboost_filesystem-mt.lib(path_traits.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::in(int &,char const *,char const *,char const * &,wchar_t *,wchar_t *,wchar_t * &)const " (__imp_?in@?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@QBEHAAHPBD1AAPBDPA_W3AAPA_W@Z)
libboost_filesystem-mt.lib(path_traits.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::out(int &,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const * &,char *,char *,char * &)const " (__imp_?out@?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@QBEHAAHPB_W1AAPB_WPAD3AAPAD@Z)
```

Here are some additional information about my project settings, which may be of help:

- `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in *Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions*
- `Multi-threaded (/MT)` in *Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library*
- `libboost_filesystem-mt.lib` and `libboost_system-mt.lib` in *Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies*
- `..\Libraries\1.54.0\lib_win32` (Boost library folder) in *Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories*
- `msvcrt.lib` and `msvcprt.lib` in *Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Ignore Specific Default Libraries*

What could be the problem? I have read on the Internet that Boost does not work very well with Qt. Could that be the problem?

Comment: `msvcrt.lib and msvcprt.lib in Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Ignore Specific Default Libraries` A lot of times this is a sign of a problem. Make sure Qt and boost were both built with the Visual Studio 2010 and you used the same CRT.

Comment: Is there a way to look if Qt and Boost have the same CRT once they are built?

Comment: Use dependency walker. if they depend on `msvcrt.dll` it is the static crt, otherwise it is a dynamic crt. For vs2010 it is named `msvcr100.dll`.

Comment: What do I have to open in Dependency Walker? Because the *.lib files cannot be opened.

Answer (score 2):

As `drescherjm` pointed out you have an different runtime libraries :

- Unless you built it yourself Qt use the dynamic version of the `CRT`
- `libboost_filesystem-mt.lib` is the static build linking to the static version of the `CRT`
- The `/MT` option specify that this project should use the static version of the `CRT` when built

Alternative 1 : Use the Multithreaded, dynamic link version of the CRT for all

- Remove `msvcrt.lib` and `msvcprt.lib` libs from *Ignore Specific Default Libraries*
- Use `boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_54.dll` and `boost_system-vc100-mt-1_54.lib`
- Use `/MD` instead of `/MT`

Alternative 2 : Built Qt yourself with `/MT` instead of `/MD`

Note:

- [Microsoft Overview of different CRT libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx)
- [boost has a guide to understand its library naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)
- [On download page of Qt you notice there are download for several versions of VS](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#)

Comment: But then I have to distribute the *.dll files with my executable right? Because that is something I want to prevent. I just want to have one file to distribute.

Comment: how did you build Qt?

Comment: I didn't build Qt myself. So I guess it uses the wrong CRT then. But what does it has to do with boost? Why am I getting linking errors for the boost library?

Comment: you are getting **linking** errors to `std::codecvt`, etc.. which are part of the CRT.

Comment: So to solve these errors, do I have to build Qt as multithreaded libs so that it uses the static version of the CRT?

Comment: Yes indeed. built it from source with the same library directives.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I still don't understand why the errors say "libboost_filesystem-mt.lib...". Could you please explain me that in more detail? Why does it not say something about Qt if the problem is the wrong build of Qt?

Comment: You break boost using `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` but if you do not use that you will have 2 crts which conflict.

Comment: Would this be the correct command for configuring the build process of Qt: `configure -debug-and-release -static -opengl desktop`? Is it the `static` option that is of importance here to create the correct set of libraries?